# Object.class.getClassLoader() gives null

Tags: java

Here is a simple demo code:

```
public class Demo {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("object - " + Object.class.getClassLoader()); // prints "object - null"
    }
}
```

I am really confused by the behavior, i.e., Object.class.getClassLoader() gives a null. So, why is that?

Comment: It's the documented behavior. Read the javadoc.

Comment: what test API are you test? Its it JUnit or TestNG?

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation for [Class.getClassLoader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--) states:

> Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.

It's normal behavior.